# JFace TreeView not launching when Input is a String

Tags: treeview, jface

I'm trying launch a simple JFace Tree.

It's acting really strange however. When I `setInput()` to be a single String, the tree opens up completely blank. However, when I set input to be a String array, it works great.

This has nothing to do with the `LabelProvider` or `ContentProvider` since these behave the same no matter what (it's a really simple experimental program).

`setInput()` is officially allowed to take any `Object`. I am confused why it will not take a String, and knowing why may help me solve my other problems in life.

Setting a single String as input:

```
TreeViewer treeViewerLeft = new TreeViewer(shell, SWT.SINGLE);
treeViewerLeft.setLabelProvider(new TestLabelProvider());
treeViewerLeft.setContentProvider(new TestCompareContentProvider());
treeViewerLeft.expandAll();
treeViewerLeft.setInput(new String("Stooge"));
```

Setting an array of Strings:

```
 TreeViewer treeViewerLeft = new TreeViewer(shell, SWT.SINGLE);
 treeViewerLeft.setLabelProvider(new TestLabelProvider());
 treeViewerLeft.setContentProvider(new TestCompareContentProvider());
 treeViewerLeft.expandAll();
 treeViewerLeft.setInput(new String[]{"Moe", "Larry", "Curly"});
```

The second works, and launches a tree using the following providers:

```
public class TestCompareContentProvider extends ArrayContentProvider implements ITreeContentProvider {

    public static int children = 0; 

    public Object[] getChildren(Object parentElement) {
        children++;
        if (children > 20){
            return null;
        }
        return new String[] {"Moe", "Larry", "Curly"};
    }
    public Object getParent(Object element) {
        return "Parent";
    }
    public boolean hasChildren(Object element) {
        if (children >20){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

and

```
public class TestLabelProvider extends LabelProvider {

    public String getText(Object element){
        return "I'm something";
    }

    public Image getImage(Object element){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've inherited [`getElements`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ITreeContentProvider.html#getElements%28java.lang.Object%29) from the `ArrayContentProvider` and that only works with arrays. You should override this method.

I don't think you need to extend `ArrayContentProvider` at all.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. I got around it by simply a one element array with the object I wanted to pass